# count docstrings as line of code in IPython

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I've noticed that line of code starts from where the docstring ends.

But it gives problem in error tracing because it points to different line than where error invoking line is actually present.

Here is simple example to demonstrate that:

```
#comments
#comments
#comments
#comments
#comments
#comments
def divide(a,b):
  a = int(a)
#convert a to an integer
  b = int(b)
#convert b to an integer
  res = a/b
#calculate result  
  return res

divide(2,0)
```

> Error

```
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-030e2eec799d> in <module>()
----> 1 divide(2,0)

<ipython-input-55-9cd1ccec09c4> in divide(a, b)
      4   b = int(b)
      5 #convert b to an integer
----> 6   res = a/b
      7 #calculate result
      8   return res

ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

error points to line no 6 whereas actual position is `12`

Is there any solution to it.

Comment: which IDE you are using? It's giving me line 12 in Sublime Text

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar IPython

Comment: What's the problem? Can't you figure out what line the traceback points to based on the information shown?

Comment: @coldspeed Yes in this case . But not when using some external library which has 1000s lines of code.

Comment: @krishna I tested your code on IPython it still says line 12

Comment: @U9-Forward Sorry. I should write Jupyter notebook instead of IPython.

Comment: @krishna I tested it on Jupyter notbook

Comment: @krishna I think what you did is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzFHr.png, so each cell contains a code and jupyter doesn't consider every cell as one code

Comment: @U9-Forward No I didn't . I should have posted image. Also I'm running it on Google colab, which I thought is Jupyter notebook.

Comment: @krishna https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxGRd.png

Comment: @U9-Forward http://prntscr.com/khwaes

Comment: @krishna See my answer

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't do Run All, so try doing:

[image: img]

(haha. sorry for my bad handwriting)

Output:

[image]

Comment: 3 thank you.Sorry for bothering.I did that.Again same result. It seems Google colab have different rules. Also this is not specific for Jupyter cell, for modules in other library too different line is pointed when error is raised.

Comment: @krishna ok, then i don't know, hope you can solve it